# t.bone SC 420 USB Microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, audio-recording

I bought a t.bone SC 420 USB Microphone.

Recording via Audacity works fine.

But as soon as the USB cable is connected to my PC, there is no more audio output.

I changed the settings, but nevertheless. The PC audio output is selected, but no sound is audible.

As soon as I unplug the USB cable of the microphone, audio output is audible again.

```
pactl list short sinks

1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
5   alsa_output.usb-0b0e_Jabra_Link_380_3050750AE0B3-00.iec958-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
7   alsa_output.usb-USB_MICROPHONE_USB_MICROPHONE_20190809-00.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

What could be the root cause?

Output of `inxi --admin --verbosity=7 --filter --no-host`: https://pastebin.com/MqF6zdVa

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the output of `inxi --admin --verbosity=7 --filter --no-host` *with the microphone plugged in* and then reply to this that you have done so, so I get a ping... 

Comment: @Fabby I added the output.

Answer (score 0):

1. click the dropdown at the top right of screen.
2. click settings.
3. in window click sound on the left.
4. in the Output section, make sure the output device is set to "Internal Speakers" or similar.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. You described the usual way to change the audio output. I am familiar with the settings, and have used it several times in the past. This change in the settings has no effect if the above microphone is connected.

Comment: That is weird...  If it is set to internal speakers, ext. device should have no effect whatsoever on output

Comment: what drivers did you install for the mic (assuming usb mic)? Maybe driver software is somehow affecting output... just a stab in the dark.

Comment: I did not install any drivers for the mic. Recording works great without installing any drivers. Except above error that audio output is blocked if the mic is connected.

Comment: is it a usb mic?nm just reread the title...

Comment: Does the vendor offer any drivers? If so try installing; I am guessing that your system sees it as output somehow. Even though you have a different output selected in settings, the Input being set to the mic may be enough, or something along these lines. If you can get ahold of a vendor supplied driver for linux, it should fix this. If not try the generic ASIO driver...